# Google App Engine cron tasks for JRuby

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, jruby

I have a Ruby script that I want to run every few minutes using Google App Engine. I don't want to run a web service, just that script. Any ideas how to do that with JRuby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout cron support on GAE:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html

Not sure what you mean by "don't want to run a web service," but this is the way to do it on GAE.